# Storing encrypted version of user's email password on my app's server

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, bcrypt

I'm working on an iOS app where I need to store user's credentials for a 3rd party service on my server. (For example, storing IMAP login/password so that when they sign into my app it fetches from their IMAP server, so my server doesn't store their email)

I am not considering OAuth since not every email service provides OAuth. To do this I was thinking about the following option:

1. User enters username/password to sign into MyApp (MyApp server implements standard security measures, meaning it stores hashed version of the password and not the raw password, so MyApp server does not know what a user's password is)
2. Once signed into MyApp, MyApp stores the raw password into local keychain.
3. User 'connects' their 3rd party email account by signing into the 3rd party email account.
4. When the 3rd party email account successfully signs in, MyApp encrypts the email's password using the MyApp password (which is stored in keychain from step 2)
5. The encrypted password is stored on MyApp's server as "emailPassword"
6. From then on, whenever user signs into MyApp, MyApp fetches the encrypted "emailPassword" from MyApp's server and decrypts it back to its original form using the MyApp password stored locally on the user's keychain (which was used to encrypt in step 4).
7. Using the raw password decrypted from step 6 MyApp fetches emails from the 3rd party email server.

I am new to encryption so not sure if this is a safe (or even possible) option. Could anyone help? Thank you.

[UPDATED] Updated to clarify concepts and changed "encoded" to "encrypted"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I updated the description to make it more clear. The reason I need MyApp's server is because I need to provide additional features on top of the email and need to tie the user's email account with MyApp's account in order to be able to do that.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to be sending the password, even encrypted, to your server? Collecting third party credentials can get you in trouble with app review, sending credentials to your own server can get you in even bigger trouble with your users, once they figure out this is going on. Why not just keep the password in the local keychain?

Comment: @zaph I updated to just get rid of that part completely because it just made the whole thing sound more confusing that it really is and was not even a necessary component in order to understand the question. Obviously the server wouldn't know what the password is if you send an encrypted version. Also the server is unable to decrypt it since only the user's local device has the raw password for the email service, which functions as the encryption key.

Comment: @pvg there are a lot of gmail apps on the appstore which needs to tie gmail's account with their app's account in order to provide custom added features. And I'm guessing most of them use OAuth. This is because Gmail provides OAuth. But most other emails don't provide OAuth. I am trying to build an app that can do this for any kind of email.

Comment: Gmail provides oAuth and gmail provides an authenticator for 2fa and app-specific passwords. But again, why would you need to send the password to your server? That seems like an unnecessary and terrible idea.

Comment: @pvg you reiterated exactly what I just said. I said "This is because Gmail provides OAuth. But most other emails don't provide OAuth. I am trying to build an app that can do this for any kind of email"

Comment: @pvg and also it would help if you can tell me why you think this is terrible idea, as I mentioned I am a newbie at encryption so don't know how insecure this scheme can be. My thesis was that since the encryption key stays on user's device keychain the server is unable to decrypt the credentials sent to it even if it tried to.

Comment: @Vlad actually, it's you who should explain this to me, if you can, because you're going to also have to explain it to your users - why do you want to store third party credentials on your server? To what purpose? I'd absolutely never give my credentials to an app that does that, short of something like a trusted password manager like 1Password or icloud keychain. This is even more perplexing a since you, as you yourself say, don't have much experience with this.

Comment: @pvg I just wanted to know if this is technically acceptable, I hope you understand I am still working on this so I can't talk about it otherwise I am just posting publicly about my yet to be launched app. All i have to say is I am not an idiot and I do realize the privacy concerns. that's why I am asking whether this is technically secure. As long as it's technically secure I am not worried about convincing users, just like how you think it's ok to give passwords to 1password

Comment: @Vlad is it possible to do in a reasonably secure way? Sure. It's not easy, easy is screwing it up. Users prefer to minimize exposure - I trust AgileBits (they publish detailed specs, for one), and if I didn't, I can just disable password sync. I know exactly why I'm using 1password - for the convenience of shared passwords across devices. You, on the other hand, still haven't articulated a good reason to store my password on your server. Why should I trust you? Why increase my risk? What do I get in return? I'm sure you know what the standard 'roll your own crypto' advice is - don't.

Answer (score -1):

You should rather say "encrypt", not "encode". Encoding is a mechanism which translates data using some set of fixed rules (algorithm). Base64 is an encoding, so is urlencoding. Encoding doesn't provide ANY security.
Encryption, however translates cleartext to ciphertext using an algorithm that uses crypto keys. Without knowledge of the key, the reversion of the ciphertext is very hard. (never impossible)
Okay, regarding your example:
It is implementable, but even though there are some attacking chances.

At some point in runtime, MyApp knows the cleartext password. At the time it is decrypted. The plaintext password then lies in RAM and could possibly read out by malicious software with respective permissions (root malware e.g.)
Also you need to make sure to use suitable algorithms in the right mode. AES-256 in CBC is more secure than in ECB mode. Then you also have to think of how to convert the password into a crypto key. Would not be too secure if you just used the password. Then you should also use a trustworthy library, no library from an unknown guy or so

Well, these are just some thoughts. You should get a little background knowledge before struggling with encryption. There are many options and you should really know, what you do.